# pytorch convolution with 0-stride along one dimension

Tags: pytorch, convolutional-neural-network

For some square images, I'd like to use torch.nn.Conv2d with the kernel as a vertical block. As in, the kernel size is defined as max value of the first dimension by 1. Since the first dimension has no more room, I'd like to have 0 stride along that first dimension. I tried using the following definition:

```
self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 32, (max_dim_0, 1),
                                    stride=(0, 1),
                                    padding=0, 
                                    dilation=1,
                                    groups=1, 
                                    bias=True, 
                                    padding_mode='zeros')
```

However, this causes my training loop throws a `RuntimeError: non-positive stride is not supported` exception. Is there a way to define the kernel as a vertical block?

Comment: does [this help](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/convolve-3d-tensor-along-one-dimension/62301)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting stride to `0` is not necessary, `torch` will simply compute with respect to the input tensor sizes, so you can set stride to `(1,1)`.

For `x` of size `(batch_size, 3, max_dim_0, max_dim_0)` (square image) the tensor output will be of size `(batch_size, 32, 1, max_dim_0)`.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me :)